# Is this sentence rewritten correctly?

Tags: reported-speech, writing

> "What do you usually do on Fridays?" she asked.

I have to rewrite this sentence using *did*.

> She wanted to know what I usually did on Fridays.

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: It would be useful to know why you think you need to use "did." Your sentence is grammatical, but likely does not mean what you intended.

Comment: If you have to use "did" for an assignment, this sentence is fine. "Did" in this case implies what activities you take part in on Fridays.

Comment: There must be more to the assignment that that. If it were *just* that, you could simply replace *do* with *did* and not change ***anything else*** about the sentence at all: *"What **did** you usually do on Fridays?" she asked.*